# I want to know the importance of features used in the test set in the svm model

Tags: python, svm

I made a binary classification svm model through `sklearn.svc`

This is my SVC model info.

```py
SVC(C=0.1, class_weight={0: 1.2306547619047619, 1: 0.8421588594704684},
    gamma=0.001, probability=True)
```

What I want to know is not the feature importance when constructing the model.

I would like to know which feature affects the test data the most when it is divided into [0,1] when new test data that is not used in the model comes in.

I have read the document of SVC, but I am not sure which attr to use, so I ask for your help.

Answer (score 0):

how about using permutation_importance function?
Here is a quick demo that you can use in your program:

```
result = permutation_importance(model, X_valid, y_valid, scoring='roc_auc', n_repeats=3, random_state=42)
pi_results_df = pd.DataFrame(result['importances'])
pi_results_df.index=X.columns
pi_results_df = pi_results_df.stack().reset_index()
pi_results_df.columns = ['feature', 'level', 'roc_auc_drop']
pi_results_df.drop(columns=['level'], inplace=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 8))
order = pi_results_df.groupby("feature").mean().reset_index().sort_values('roc_auc_drop', ascending=False).feature
ax = sns.barplot(x="roc_auc_drop", y="feature", data=pi_results_df, estimator=np.mean, ci=85, capsize=.2, color='lightblue', orient='h', order=order)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you.
I wonder if this code is suitable for a single test data.